# Yii2 rule array validation

Tags: validation, yii2

I have 2 models A and B where A has many B.
Now i want to create multiple B at the same time(page).
Here is my codes.

B.php

```
...
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'xx', 'yy'], 'required'],
            [['xx', 'yy'], 'string'],
            [['username'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }
...
```

_form.php

```
<div class="b-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?php for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
?>
<h3>B #<?=$i+1?></h3>
<hr />
    <?= $form->field($model, 'xx[]')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'yy[]')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?php 
    }
?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

I want to make those 6(3x2) text inputs responds individually and at least need 2 pairs of `xx` and `yy` to pass validation.

Now how do i build good rules to cover my needs?

Answer (score 0):

There is dedicated section about it in official docs - [Collecting Tabular Input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html).

Example of controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Setting;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $settings = Setting::find()->indexBy('id')->all();

        if (Model::loadMultiple($settings, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($settings)) {
            foreach ($settings as $setting) {
                $setting->save(false);
            }
            return $this->redirect('index');
        }

        return $this->render('update', ['settings' => $settings]);
    }
}
```

Used methods:

- [Model::loadMultiple()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#loadMultiple()-detail) - load post data into an array of models.
- [Model::validateMultiple()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#validateMultiple()-detail) - validates an array of models.

There is more info, for example how to create a dynamic set of new records, use it if you need it.

Also, take a look to some extensions for easing work with multiple inputs, for example [unclead/yii2-multiple-input](https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input) or [wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform).

> I want to make those 6(3x2) text inputs responds individually and at
>   least need 2 pairs of xx and yy to pass validation.

This sounds weird, you should never trust and always validate ALL data coming from user.

Comment: first of all,thankyou for advice about:This sounds weird, you should never trust and always validate ALL data coming from user